# How to make text appear when input box is active

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I dont really know why this doesn't work. Im trying to make the text 'press enter to search' to appear when the input box is active. BUT it doesn't work with the CSS I have for some reason. How do you do it?

HTML:

```
<form action="http://google.com/search">
<p class='inp'><input type='text' name='q'class='searchBox' placeholder='What do you want to search for George?' >
<span id='prompt'>Enter to search</p></span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#prompt{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-left:30px;
    opacity:0;

}


.searchBox:focus > #prompt{
    color:#000;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Your html structure is wrong, closing p tag then span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following css:

```
.searchBox:focus + #prompt {
  color: #000;
  visibily: visible;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5fvh5mj/)

`#prompt` element is the next sibling of `.searchBox`. `.searchBox:focus > #prompt` doesn't work because `>` means child.

Reference: [Selectors - Web developer guides | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information_Selectors_based_on_relationships)

Comment: Great :) Also don't forget to accept the most suitable answer, because people might keep posting answers thinking you haven't found a solution to your problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

i made two changes 
use label not span, and to access in css use "+" not ">"
and this is my codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKjryV

```
    #prompt{
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-left:30px;
    visibly:hidden;

}


.searchBox:focus + #prompt{
    color:#000;
    visibily:visible;
}
<form action="http://google.com/search">
<input type='text' name='q'class='searchBox' id='iEl' placeholder='What do you want to search for George?' >
<label for='iEl' id='prompt'>Enter to search</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html structure is wrong, closing p tag then span. It should be

```
<span id='prompt'>Enter to search</span></p>
```

Then the css should be

```
.searchBox:focus + #prompt
```

In css selector div > p means select all "p" elements where the parent is a "div" element.

And div + p means selects all "p" elements that are placed immediately after "div" elements.

So the 2nd one is appropriate for you.